# Livereload not working Ionic cordova deploying to real device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, console.log, livereload

I'm working with ionic 3.9.2 cordova 8.1.2.

I'm using using real device for testing android project and my livereload is not working. I'm using `ionic cordova run android -lc.` My project is running fine but i didn't get any logs in cmd and livereload is not working too [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4vey.png).

But i get logs in `chrome://inspect` and after a while get an error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdcaD.png).

I used `ionic cordova run android -lc --debug` for more details still not showing logs.

Then i tried to make adb connection. But still no luck or I'm not using it correctly [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYC8t.png).

I also tried to delete and reinstall ws package from node_modules but still no improvement.

Here's my environment

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.3
Node: 10.11.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.10.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.0.35
@angular-devkit/core              7.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.0.3
@angular/cli                      7.0.3
@schematics/angular               7.0.3
@schematics/update                0.10.3
rxjs                              5.5.11
typescript                        2.6.2
webpack                           3.12.0
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, this looks like a network error caused by a Firewall or Antivirus.
Did you try it on a Different computer/OS or Different Phone/Emulator? It would show which device is responsible for the timeout. It is probably your Computer, but I don't know what Software your Phone has installed and/or what Version of Android you have.

Maybe also check out your Dev options and allow Everything that's related to Networking

Comment: I've tried other devices and same result even after turning off firewall. And livereload is working fine on win 10. Win 8 and 7 cause problem. I don't know whether its an OS problem. And I don't have time to change my OS. I'm currently using win 8.

Comment: If it's not the system it has to be the tools (ionic/cordova/adb). Try using a ionic 4 beta (node 10, angular 7) startup project and update cordova to newest. If that doesn't work it has to be adb, but you already tried it on different Installations so that would not make any sense (in my opinion)

Comment: ionic 4 is not stable. I'm unable to create a project even. Could you guide me what might be problem with adb?

Comment: I am developing all my apps already in ionic 4, new projects only fail if you use the wrong packages (not @beta), would be helpful to know if it works because I have no idea what could be the problem with your system.